# Is there a way to get the jQueryUI tab element by index?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to be able to do stuff to the selected tab and the tab before it. I can get the index of the selected tab like so:

```
var selectedIndex = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
```

So I'd like to do something like

```
$leftTab = $tabs.getTabByIndex(selectedIndex - 1);
```

Is there something approximating this? Or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: If you show your HTML code, it'll be easier to help, because I'm not familiar with the tabs plugin you are talking about (that is if you are actually using a plugin).

Comment: By "tab before it" do you mean the tab to the left of the selected tab, or the previously selected tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$tabs` is the container around your tab `div` elements, try this:

```
$leftTab = $("div", $tabs).eq(selectedIndex - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, eq() was exactly what I was looking for. I had to modify it a little bit: $leftTab = $("li").eq(selected - 1); but that was def the idea!